# Is there a way to display plus sign near the positive the tick values?

Tags: ticks

Let's say I have a code like shown below:

```
ListPlot[{{1,1},{2,1},{3,-1},{4,-1}}]
```

An output is shown on the figure.

[image: Output]

The "-" (minus) sign is shown near the negative tick values of the Y axis. Is there a straightforward way to make the "+" (plus) appear near the corresponding positive values, i.e. "+0.5" and "+1.0"?

Comment: does `Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, 
     NumberForm[#, {3, 1}, NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}, 
      NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}]} & /@ {-1.0, -0.5, 0.5, 1.}}` give what you need?

Comment: .. or `PaddedForm[#, {2, 1}, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}]` instead of `NumberForm[...`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[tF]
tF[divs_: {6, 6}] := Join @@ 
 {{#, PaddedForm[N@#, {3, 1}, NumberSigns -> {"-", "+"}], {0.02, 
           0}} & /@ #[[1]], 
  {#, ""} & /@ DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[#[[2]]]} & @ FindDivisions[{##}, divs] &;

ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, -1}, {4, -1}}, Ticks -> {tF[{10, 6}], tF[]}]
```

[image]